# Grouping values in an aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm quite new to Elasticsearch.

I have a query that looks like this:

```
GET animals/_search

{
  "aggregations" : {
    "top_animals" : {
      "terms" : {"field" : "animals", "size" : 10}
    }
  },
  "size" : 0
}
```

This returns something like:

```
{
  (...)
  "aggregations": {
    "top_animals": {
      (...)
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "dogs",
          "doc_count": 100
        },
        {
          "key": "whales",
          "doc_count": 70
        },
        {
          "key": "dolphins",
          "doc_count": 50
        },
        {
          "key": "cats",
          "doc_count": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I've been given a list of animals that are equivalent and should be counted together.
So "dogs" and "cats" are "pets", and "dolphins" and "whales" are "aquatic_mammals".

I'd like a result like this (note that the results are ordered):

```
{
  (...)
  "aggregations": {
    "top_animals": {
      (...)
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "aquatic_mammals",
          "doc_count": 120
        },
        {
          "key": "pets",
          "doc_count": 110
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How should I modify my query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, the values `pets` and `aquatic` are not part of the stored data?

There's probably a way with a script (which I can't test, so... good luck!), something like:

```
GET animals/_search

{
  "aggregations" : {
    "top_animals" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field": "animals",
        "script" : {
          "source": """
            if (_value == 'cats' || _value == 'dogs') {
              return 'pets';
            } else if (_value == 'whales' || _value == 'dolphins') {
              return 'aquatic';
            } else {
              return 'alien';
            }
          """,
          "lang": "painless"
        },
        "size" : 10
      }
    }
  },
  "size" : 0
}
```

Here, `_value` is set because a `"field"` is targeted. Check the Terms Aggregation [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script).

It's quite boring to write because [`switch` doesn't seem to exist](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-statements.html) in their language, but it should do the trick. Also, a more skilled programmer might have shorter/better ways of writing this script: I've never had much use of this "painless" scripting.

Hope this helps. And works. ;)

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks! If calculations have to be made on the data, how does performance?

Comment: @Alan good point, I have no idea but since they use a language close to their core Java, it is expected to be quite good. With a populated index, you can try 2 ways: loop 1k times on this request, and compare when looping 1k times on your request + doing the structure transformation in your back-end code. If the difference is not astonishing, you'll have to consider which system - back-end or ES - is best suited for high loads (ES is "almost naturally" scalable in clusters, your back-end might be "load-balancable" too, only you know this and the costs involved).